# MySQL dropping unique pair

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

In a table of my database I made the unfortunate mistake of making a pair of fields unique when creating the database

```
UNIQUE(A,B)
```

I now want to remove this constraint. How can I do this in MySQL syntax?

I know for a single index I can do

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP Index A
```

But I'm not sure how to do it for pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key still has a name, and it's probably `A` unless you also made `A` a key first or gave it a specific name.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP INDEX A
```

should actually work.  Look at the table definition (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`) to see what the actual name of the key is.